# Troubleshooting MySQL UPDATE efficiency: UPDATE SELECT vs UPDATE INNER JOIN vs create an index vs another issue

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-update, dbeaver

MySQL database in DBeaver 23.3.0.

I have an UPDATE that is very slow and I cannot figure out why: tableA is 1.4 million rows, tableB is 1300 records and only contains the id. I need to update 3 columns. I've tried two approaches:

**Approach 1:**

```
UPDATE tableA
SET col1 = 1, col2 = 0, col3 = 0 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tableB);
```

**Approach 2:**

```
UPDATE tableA a
INNER JOIN tableB ON a.id = b.id
SET col1 = 1, col2 = 0, col3 = 0;
```

I thought Approach 2 would be faster but I'm not sure how to test this. Based on the time it takes to execute a SELECT version of each, 1 is faster (91s vs 191s) but after testing on a subset of tableA  (5000 rows), 2 was slightly faster (5057s vs 5460s).

I tried executing each UPDATE, but cancelled after waiting ~10 minutes. It doesn't seem that this operation should be so slow and I will need to do similar operations on these tables.

**Questions:**

- Should I create an index from tableB? Approach 1 seems that it is using tableB as an index and Approach 2 should subset tableA and limit the UPDATE to 1300 rows, so I'm having trouble seeing how an index would improve things
- Is there something else that could cause this operation to be slow? Database too big? Settings in DBeaver? Allocation of memory?

Comment: You should index id in both tables use approach 2 and run an explain on the update statement.

Comment: Does `table1` have more columns (i.e. there are columns which shouldn't be updated)?

Comment: @Akina Yes, there are 20 columns total.

Comment: @P.Salmon This solved my problem - tableA had lost its primary key at some point in my previous work due to sloppy table copying. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

- `UPDATE` must do a lot more work.  It must save the old value of each changed row in case of a crash or `ROLLBACK`.
- [Re: "execute a SELECT version of each"]  `IN ( SELECT ... )` should be avoided.  *Sometimes* the Optimizer can turn it into a more efficient construct such as `EXISTS` or `JOIN`.  Instead, you should do the conversion for it (where practical).
- In old versions of MySQL, the Optimizor for `UPDATE` was different than for the 'equivalent' `SELECT`.
- To discuss further (and if you have a newer version of MySQL), please provide `EXPLAIN UPDATE...` and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE ...`
- When timing queries, run each query twice -- the first run may be bogged down in loading stuff from disk while the second runs faster due to caching.
- Whenever using `JOIN`, qualify each column with the table name (or alias).
- If `id` is not already the `PRIMARY KEY` in each table, the let's discuss indexing.  (Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)